# Issues In Intent Passing Using Database

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My problem is how to pass Rating bar value in to another activity using another putExtra method?any one solve this problem? 
Here is my First activity

```
public void giveRating(View v)


    {
            String Name =  spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Float Rating = ratingBar.getRating();
        String query = "insert into Rating values('"+Name+"',"+Rating+")";
        try
        {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
            AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ab.setMessage("DATA SAVED");
            ab.show();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("InsertionException",""+e);
        }
    }
    public void viewRating(View v)
    {
        try {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String query = "select * from Rating";
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
            boolean res = cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (res) {
                do {
                    String Name = cursor.getString(0);
                    String Rating = cursor.getString(1);

                    sb.append(Name + ":" + Rating+"\n");
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } else {

                AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                ab.setMessage("No data To read");
                ab.show();
            }

            String value = sb.toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Items.class);
            i.putExtra("k1", value);
            startActivity(i);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ReadDataEXception",""+e);
        }
```

Second Activity

```
TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.items_layout);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String name;
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        name= b.getString("k1");
        textView.setText(name);
        textView.setTextSize(20);
```

Database Activity

```
 public Database(Context c)


    {
        super(c,DBNAME,null,VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        try {
            String query = "create table Rating(Name TEXT,Rating REAL)";
            db.execSQL(query);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("TableCreationException",""+e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please write your conclusion. If you have in error then give error log.

Comment: what's the problem with current code

Comment: No problem with my current code.but i want pass float value using another putExtra method.

Comment: @anilkumarjohn : Dude do you have single name and rating values in your db or an array of name and rating values ?? You mean you want to pass array of names and ratings to next Activity ???

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add another `putExtra` with `keyName` like

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Items.class);
    i.putExtra("name", name);
    i.putExtra("rating",rating);
    startActivity(i);
```

And get from Items activity

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String name;
    String rating;

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    name= b.getString("name");
    rating= b.getString("rating");

    textView.setText(name);
    textView1.setText(rating);

    textView.setTextSize(20);
```

Hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: but its not working i m already try this code earlier.but here rating is float value

Comment: //use this code

Intent i = getIntent();
        String name;
        float rating;
        
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        name= b.getString("name");
        rating = b.getFloatExtra("rating", 0);
        
        textView.setText(name);
        textView1.setText(String.valueOf(rating);
        
        textView.setTextSize(20);

Comment: then in main activity what is for float

Comment: in main activity simply do same as before .no change in main activity .